# Sharing eclipse project over SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, qt

We want to share an eclipse Qt project via an SVN repository.
Of course we need to share the .pro file of Qt to be able to build the project.

The problem is, that without the project files you can not handle the project in eclipse but we cannot use the same as they contain local references.

Also it would be nice to use the Eclipse SVN plugin to manage this.

I already tried to check out the project and create a Qt project on Checkout but this overwrites the checked-out project file.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

These are some lines from the .cproject file that are autogenerated, so I can not change the absolute paths:

```
<storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.pathentry">
        <pathentry base-path="/usr/include/qt4" include="" kind="inc" path="" system="true"/>
        <pathentry base-path="/usr/include/qt4" include="QtWebKit" kind="inc" path="" system="true"/>
        ...
```

Comment: Could you add an example for a `*.pro` file? Has that only auto-generated content, or do you manually change it?

Comment: Why using local references? Relative paths are supported.

Comment: mliebelt: It should be only auto-generated @webclectic: I don't know what kind of references are saved in the .project files. But even if everything is relative the path seperator could change (we have Win and Linux). Also I do not know wether the global includes are written down in the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found following solution:

No .cproject .project file in SVN!

1. Import the code files from SVN (also the .pro file for Qt)
2. Eclipse will ask you to create a project, so create a Qt Project with the same name (or some else, but you will then have to delete the files)
3. When the project was created, revert it (right MB on the Project in Project Explorer -> Team -> Revert) to the state of the repo checkout
4. Done, now you can work with the project

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 rules for Subversion (independent of Eclipse, should be the same all the time):

- If the tool will regenerate a file, and you don't have to change it:

  ==> don't check it in your version management (may it Subversion, Git, CVS, ...).
- If the file contains parts that are manually changed by a user

  ==> it should be checked into version management.

If you have the second case (not clear from your question), you should try to change the paths to be relative, so that others could use your project at the same location.

If you cannot change that, stick to the location in the file system. Every developer has to use an identical setup.

If you have to support different operating systems, and the files generated by the tooling are not compliant (shame on the tool makers), you should hold templates for all operating systems in your version management, and should initially (manually) make a copy, depending on the operating system you are working in.

If you have to change that file for some purpose, you have to change the templates as well and should remember that all developers have to make a new copy after that.

Sorry, I don't know Qt and have never developed in a C-environment on different platforms, so my tips are pretty vague.

Comment: Ok so it mainly concerns the .project and .cproject files that hold for example the includepaths. Now I can import files from SVN in Eclipse but only as a project. So either I would have to create a project from this file (which in turn has to be a Qt project to support Qt, but overwrites most of the imported files) or I can create a project and try to import the files into the project (the latter I am about to try right now).

Comment: Try to create a new empty project, and look at the meta data generated by eclipse. Try to copy the necessary metadata to a project checked out from Subversion. If that is not sufficient, try to close and reopen the project then.

Comment: Well after some tries I found an acceptable way, check out my answer if you are interested in it.